# cant start server in eclipse after switch to openjdk

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently downloaded and unziped openJdk 14
I then went to Eclipse > Java > Installed JREs and set the new jdk to be used
[image]

However after doing this I am no longer able to run my server (tomcat webapp)
I get an error from the jdk

[image]

as well as a generic error in eclipse saying it failed to start

When googling around it said to check my paths, but as far as i can tell they are correct:

(user variable)

%JAVA_HOME% = C:\JavaProgramFiles\jdk-14.0.2

(system & user variable)

Path  %JAVA_HOME%\bin

Update 1 (FYI removed some path stuff as it doesnt seem relevant anymore):

thanks @KunLun

when cd'ing into the bin directory, javac -version worked.  I reviewed environment variables again and this time added %JAVA_HOME%/bin to my User's Path variable (previously it was only in system path).  So now javac -version works from any directory.  **However Eclipse still has same error** when i start my server, though i do get this new msg in the console?

> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:\JavaProgramFiles\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\endorsed
> is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular
> form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.

Comment: Maybe it's a problem with jdk you downloaded. Can you provide use the link for download?

Comment: https://jdk.java.net/14/

Comment: `%JAVA_HOME% = C:\JavaProgramFiles\jdk-14.0.2` - looks wrong `JavaProgramFiles`. In your Environment Variable is like that?

Comment: should be right, it was like that previous just different jdk

Comment: Try this: In Command Prompt: `cd C:\JavaProgramFiles\jdk-14.0.2\bin`, then execute `javac -version`. If it works, means is something wrong at variable

Comment: It's been a while since I've looked at Server definitions in Eclipse. You should examine that closely. How does it specify what JVM to use to run the server?

Comment: Which release of Eclipse and the Web Tools is this?

Comment: Eclipse: 2020-06, im not sure about web tools (how can i get that?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message you quoted shows the cause of the problem. When the server instance was defined, the JVM launch arguments set for it included a reference to endorsed directories, an argument valid through Java 8, but not for Java 9 and newer. When you open the editor for your server instance from inside the Servers View, in the **General Information** section, Click on the **Runtime Environment** link and change the JRE explicitly to a Java 8 version. The server should then start up again.

[image: Changing the JRE used to launch Tomcat]

Comment: it was set to Workbench default JRE, I changed it to JDK 14 but error persist.  as you mention these "endorsed directories" seem to be the issue.  However its required that i run my local environment with jdk 14  (our dev enviroment needs to be the same as when its published)

Comment: I had to remove -Djava.endorsed.dirs="C:\JavaProgramFiles\tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.21\endorsed" from the arguments in Open Launch configuration > Arguments