# Cannot configure Apache Tomcat 9 with JDK 10.0.1 in Eclipse Oxygen

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat

This is my first problem here, I look forward to have a great interaction.

Please help me I have to show this working to my mentor tomorrow.

I was making a Dynamic web project file in eclipse oxygen that needed tomcat server to launch. I have JDK 10.0.1 as my Java version. also it was showing JAVA SE 10 at some places. So when I tried to add Tomcat 8 and 9 either of them, there was an error

```
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=C:...apache-tomcat-9.0.14\endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
```

I searched it on stackoverflow and got this link
[How do you replace endorsed directory in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46419496/how-do-you-replace-endorsed-directory-in-java-9). but somehow I do not know how to do it.

One solution I thought of downloading lower version of JDK and then trying to make it possible.

Please help me community if there is a way to do so.

Thanks.

Comment: Oxygen is 3 years old. This problem shouldn't exist on the current release.

Comment: I am using latest version. but still this problem is there. how can i eliminate this.

Comment: Eclipse Oxygen is **not** the latest version, the current version is Eclipse 2020-06

Comment: I am using Eclipse Java oxygen. Not being proper from development background, if I delete it to download new one I don't think I can configure and start using java codes in them. I have to show the remaining codes too tomorrow. So if someone can help me in Java Oxygen version that would be really helpful.

Comment: Java 9 and 10 didn't exist when that release came out. It will not handle Tomcat properly with those runtimes. I wrote the original fix for that problem, so when I say that won't work, believe me. You can try to go back to running it with Java 8, and even then, making the changes from the comments in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63178967/cant-start-server-in-eclipse-after-switch-to-openjdk/63184727#63184727, and that still might not fix the problem completely.

Comment: So I downloaded Java 8 got everything configured and did according to the link that was provided by you. 
Now a new type of error is
``` WARNING: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library failed to load. 
The error reported was [C.....apache-tomcat-9.0.14\bin\tcnative-1.dll: 
Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform] java.lang.
UnsatisfiedLinkError: C....apache-tomcat-9.0.14\bin\tcnative-1.dll: Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform ``` What I should do now.

Comment: Run either a 32-bit Tomcat with a 32-bit Java, or better a 64-bit Tomcat with a 64-bit Java. In your case, you have a 64-bit Java, but a 32-bit Tomcat and this does not work.